# fetch sql data between two month and two given year

Tags: sql

[image]

I want to fetch data from table in between 6 2014 to 4 2016.
but this not return any value what is the solution for this..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask]. For starters, please don't include an image of code or data. Instead, copy and paste your code or data here. They're pretty useless, especially if someone is faced with retyping said code/data in their response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following SQL query to select data from table between two selected month and two given year.

```
SELECT * FROM usr_hired_duration where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',LPAD(month,2,'01'),'-',LPAD(payment_date,2,'01')), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2014,'-',LPAD(03,2,'01'),'-',LPAD(01,2,'01')), '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2016,'-',LPAD(06,2,'01'),'-',LPAD(01,2,'01')), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Similar to my first query, but probably slower since a lot of conversions are performed. Take a look at my second query instead, will most probably outperform both this and my first query.

Answer (score 0):

Show your query what you had tried or else

Try using **BETWEEN** Query.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (month BETWEEN 4 AND 6) AND (year BETWEEN 2014 AND 2016);
```

Comment: this works fine but when i change the  position of 4 and 6 ..then show empty row.  SELECT * FROM usr_hired_duration WHERE (month BETWEEN 6 AND 4 ) AND (year BETWEEN 2014 AND 2016)

Comment: it won't work. because first condition fails. and you need to understand what between does...BETWEEN returns values that fall within a given range.
BETWEEN is a shorthand for >= AND <=.
BETWEEN operator is inclusive: begin and end values are included.

Comment: Wont return November 2015 dates.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see the query u tried first.  but try this.

```
 select *
 from table
 where datecolumn >= '2014-06-01' and datecolumn <= '2016-04-01'
```

Comment: thnks but this is not working. i am not getting desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Add the years * 100 and months to get integer values formatted as YYYYMM:

```
select *
from tablename
where (year * 100 + month) between (2014 * 100 + 4) and (2016 * 100 + 6)
```

Or, if your dbms support *Row and table constructors*:

```
select *
from tablename
where (year, month) between (2014, 4) and (2016, 6)
```